# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: error, syntax, profile

suddenly an error shows up on my site. It's happening only one user's profile page. All other profiles seem to work fine.
It's EE 2.5.2
I have no clue where to start looking for the error.

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(680) : eval()'d code on line 245"

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the data in the user´s profile? It might be a strange character. Maybe copy all the data to a text editor like sublimetext or notepad and copy -paste it back